# Maven 2.2 Eclipse Target is not a supported Maven Home

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-2

I've a problem to link Maven 2.2 installed in disk with eclipse (I'm not able to uncheck the embedded version).

[image: Maven Installations]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maven 2.2.1 itself is more than ten years old ...why do you like to use such an extreme old version?

Comment: I am working on an old project, I want to recover it on my machine

Comment: Then you have to use old versions of the tools. Need to use old Eclipse version or you have to stick with plain command line ...and I can suggest to migrate that project to Maven 3.X at least....

Comment: Yes that's what I'm tying to do (using an ancien eclipse version -> Luna), upgrading the Maven version is not the priority in this moment, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use ECLIPSE LUNA and Maven 2.2.1 was accepted.